# Angular2 - Show component name and its html template path in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have thought of having debugger component in angular2 application which is similar like "Show Template Path" in magento ecommerce feature.

[image]

I would like to show the template path on left side and component name from right side of the red bar in DOM itself by trigger the shortcut keys.This could help the developer on debugging the large application.

Kindly advise me, what could be the best possible way of implementing this debugging component. This component should shows every component level information on respective piece of DOM which is being rendered from component used in that page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Update based on comments:**

Use the Reflect package [here](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata)

After importing it in all your components, use the Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', ComponentClass) method.

From that you can extract your templateURL.

**Old**

You can use the activatedRoute Interface: [Here](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute)

It has the URL of the current route and also the component which is activated.

Create a service called DebuggerService and have a property called routeMap in it and provide it in the app.module. Import and inject this service on every component.

So now in every component's onInit or Constructor, you can do something like this:

```
@Component({...})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, debugger: DebuggerService) {
    this.debugger.routeMap += (this.router.url + '' + this.router.routeConfig.component.name)
  }
}
```

What you are basically doing is concatenating each route that is activated inside the service. This value will be stored throughout the application because it is globally provided in app.module.

You can now use this property of the debuggerService in your debuggerComponent and print out all routes.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I am using template url as 'templateUrl: 'app/test/test-info.component.html'... i could not find the url given in component from (this.route.url.map(segments => segments.join('')) + '     ' + this.route.component). Please advise

Comment: Updating my answer

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Comment: This is fine but i could not get the template url path. I want to show complete path app/test/test-info.component.html. how do we get that?

Comment: I tried with this.router.url. But in console, [object Object] componentName.... I just need templateUrl to show

Comment: Do you need the physical path to the template? Or do you want the path shown in the url of the browser?

Comment: I need physical template path used in component. For example, I want to show this complete path app/test/test-info.component.html in DOM. Thats how magento show their respective section template in DOM

Comment: Please check updated answer. You may have to use a third party package called reflect